# How can I access offers of a public page via facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

The documentation on endpoint `/{page-id}/nativeoffers` clearly states that we need the page-id and pages_manage_ads permissions to access offers on a public page. Also the person who requested the token should have `ADVERTISE` role on page. Here is the [link to the documentation of graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/nativeoffers/).

**Current Situation**

- I have the pages_manage_ads permission on specific user_token.
- The user is admin of the facebook page and have role in developer console app too.
- The app is yet in development mode.

**Problem:**
When I try to access the offers of the page using the endpoint `/{page-id}/nativeoffers`, it returns me empty data despite the fact that offers are present on the page I am trying to access.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: You are talking about the user token, but did you actually use a page token for the request?

Comment: @CBroe yes I did passed the page access token in the fields of API call. Also, I have successfully retrieved the posts and events of public page using the endpoints `{page-id}/feed` and `{page-id}/events` respectively using the same method. But somehow I can't access the page offers.

Comment: How did you acquire the page access token? What do you get, when you put that token through the token debug tool?

Comment: @CBroe I got the page access token using the `{user-id}` and `{user-access-token}` in the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/accounts?access_token={user-access_token}`. When I debug the token I get the expiry-date (which is definitely a future date) and the list of permissions that I have for the particular user.

Comment: Then I’d try and file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs